# Replacing a substring of an element's text with another string

Tags: javascript, jquery

## The Problem

I'm trying to use the JavaScript string `replace` method to replace some text in a div if it contains a certain string. However, my code does not replace the string inside that div.

### The Javascript

```
function john(){
  var NAME = "Johnny Buffet,";
  var val = $("div#like-list-").text();
  if ( val.indexOf(NAME) !== -1 ){
      val.replace(NAME, '');      
  }
}
```

Comment: **THERE IS NO** jQuery `replace()` function

Comment: replace is a javascript method and you need to update the text of your element, because right now you're just operating on the variable and not saving the edited string anywhere

Comment: @koala_dev: "you're just changing the variable" --- nope, that's incorrect

Comment: @zerkms fixed the wording on my comment

Comment: @Leighton: There is also the manual how to change the text of an element with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a String function and **not** a jQuery function; Strings in JavaScript are immutable, so `.replac()` returns the modified String which you then have to reassign to your element.

That said, you can use [`.text(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) to perform the replacement in a single step:

```
$("div#like-list-").text(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(NAME, '');
});
```

Btw, I've removed the `.indexOf()` condition as well, because if NAME doesn't occur inside your string, the `.replace()` function will just return the original string.

Answer (score 1):

You're editing the string, then simply throwing it away. Take the edited val and put it's contents back into the HTML element using a parameterized call to the `text` method.

```
function john(){
  var NAME = "Johnny Buffet,";
  var val = $("div#like-list-").text();
  if ( val.indexOf(NAME) !== -1 ){
      $("div#like-list-").text(val.replace(NAME, ''));
  }
}
```

Comment: @Leighton You're welcome, though [@Jack's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18179972/803925) is probably a cleaner approach. If any of these answers solves your problem, remember to mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` is javascript not jQuery and you need to reset the value to variable after replace as replace() returns the updated text;
ie;

```
val = val.replace(NAME, '');
```

so try:

```
function john(){
  var NAME = "Johnny Buffet,";
  var val = $("div#like-list-").text();
  if ( val.indexOf(NAME) !== -1 ){
     val = val.replace(NAME, '');      
  }
}
```